# Classes nested into an interface

Tags: java, interface, static, nested-class, jls

**Why is it possible to define inner (aka *non-static nested*) classes into an interface?**

Does it make any sense? They cannot exists within an instance of the containing interface, because interfaces cannot be instantiated, so...

The following does compile:

```
interface MyInterface
{
    static class StaticNestedClass
    {
        static int a()
        {
            return 0;
        }
        int b()
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    class InnerClass
    {
        static int a()
        {
            return 0;
        }
        int b()
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any difference between the 2 above classes? Is `static` actually taken into account?
Note that if you change `interface` with `class`, you obviously get a compile error on `InnerClass`' `static int a()`.

Furthermore, have a look at the following:

```
interface MyInterface
{
    int c=0;
    static class StaticNestedClass
    {
        static int a()
        {
            return c;
        }
        int b()
        {
            return c+1;
        }
    }
    class InnerClass
    {
        static int a()
        {
            return c;
        }
        int b()
        {
            return c+1;
        }
    }
}
```

Unlike when the outer *containing entity* is a class, here of course there is no such thing as "an inner (non-static nested) class can access outer's fields while a static nested class can't", because, given that our outer thingie is an interface, our `c` integer is implicitly static... Are `interface`'s nested classes implicitly static too?

So once again, are `StaticNestedClass` and `InnerClass` just the same?

Comment: I **think** `class InnerClass` is implicitly static, similarly to `c`

Comment: @Cruncher in fact, any non-method in an interface is marked as `static` by the compiler automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class InnerClass
```

is implicitly(converted to by the compiler as per [JLS, Section 9.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.5))

> A member type declaration in an interface is implicitly static and
>   public. It is permitted to redundantly specify either or both of these
>   modifiers.

```
static class InnerClass
```

because it is in an interface.

You will get the error when changing interface to class, because non-static Inner Classes are not allowed, and it's not implicitly converted to static in the case of a class.

To answer your final question directly,

yes, `StaticNestedClass` and `InnerClass` are just the same

Comment: [The JLS, Section 9.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.5) talks about interface members being implicitly `static`, which includes member classes.

Comment: @rgettman I was looking for the specific JLS section. I came across that, and wasn't sure if that part covered inner classes. Thanks, will add to post. EDIT: nevermind, I was at 9.3, 9.5 is rather explicit to this

Comment: Thank you Cruncher and rgettman, the JLS 9.5 section is exactly what I was looking for.